# R: fill down multiple columns

Tags: r, fill, tidyr

I'm using fill() from the tidyr package. `fill(df, colname1, colname2, colname3)` works fine, until I found a dataset with 32 variables. How should I fill down all columns without typing each name?

I've tried:

```
fill(df,colnames(df)),
fill(df,1:32), 
fill(df,colname1:colname32).
```

and produced the following errors:

```
Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  colnames(df1)

Error: tinyformat: Not enough conversion specifiers in format string

Error: tinyformat: Not enough conversion specifiers in format string
```

Comment: Given that you say fill(df, 1:32) does not work, and the regular evaluation option provided below does not either, there might be some problem with your data frame (class of that object)? Can you provide output of `class(df)` and also `str(df)`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

We can use `fill_` when we select variables with `names`.

```
library(tidyr)# using tidyr_0.4.1.9000
res <- fill_(df, names(df))
head(res)
#   col1 col2 col3
#1    1   NA    b
#2    1    3    b
#3    2    4    a
#4    2    4    a
#5    2    1    a
#6    3    4    a
```

Other option would be

```
fill(df, everything())
```

However, if we use `fill` with `names(df))`, it will give the same error as the OP showed

```
fill(df, names(df)[1])
#Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
#The following do not:
#*  names(df)[1]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
 df <- data.frame(col1= sample(c(NA, 1:3), 20, replace=TRUE), 
                  col2 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 20, replace=TRUE),
                  col3 = sample(c(NA, letters[1:5]), 20, replace=TRUE),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: it gives the following error: Error: tinyformat: Not enough conversion specifiers in format string

Comment: @woshishui  It works for the example I showed.  As you haven't showed a reproducible example, it is difficult to comment

Comment: @woshishui  I also tried with a mixed class dataset.  It is working for me.

Comment: Perhaps version problem? Output of `packageVersion('tidyr')` can be useful. Strange that `fill(df, 1:32)` won't work.

Comment: @Gopala Yes, it could be the version difference.  As the OP didn't show any reproducible example, it is hard to know.

Comment: tidyr version is 0.4.1, it does have multiple column types, but it still doesn't work even when I converted everything into chr. It is read into R using openxlsx::read.xlsx. Trying to create an reproducable example now.

Comment: @woshishui  My version is `0.4.1.9000`

Comment: @ akrun: how do you get that? update.packages("tidyr") only brings me up to 0.4.1.

Comment: I have `0.4.1` and works fine with the sample data frame created by Akrun. Are you sure you have the underscore after fill like `fill_()`?

Comment: akrun and Gopala, while trying to reproduce the data, I found a NA in column names. While read.xlsx import the data, a column name with ' was passed in the data frame as NA. This caused the issue with fill(). After fixing the issue all three method fill_(df, names(df)), fill(df,1:32) and fill(df, colname1:colname32) worked. Should I delete this question? It can be missleading? Thanks for your help, because if you didn't point out what I did right, I wouldn't know where went wrong.

Comment: @woshishui You can keep it as I also included the `fill_` option which would work with `names`

Answer (score 4):

Building off @akrun's comment and data, here are two other ways using the tidyr:

**Data**

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(col1= sample(c(NA, 1:3), 20, replace=TRUE), 
                 col2 = sample(c(NA, 1:5), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 col3 = sample(c(NA, letters[1:5]), 20, replace=TRUE),
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**Two Options**

```
#Specify column names
fill(df, c("col1", "col2"), .direction = "down")

#Specify range of columns
fill(df, c(col1:col3), .direction = "down")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative with package `zoo` which can also fill backwards if desired.
On the sample created above-

```
zoo::na.locf(df)

   col1 col2 col3
1     2    4    e
2     2    4    e
3     3    4    a
4     2    4    b
5     1    3    d
6     2    4    d
7     2    1    b
8     1    1    e
9     3    3    e
10    1    2    e
11    1    4    e
12    1    1    e
13    3    1    a
14    3    4    c
15    3    3    b
16    2    3    e
17    3    1    e
18    3    2    b
19    3    5    c
20    3    5    e
```

where `df` is

```
   col1 col2 col3
1     2    4    e
2     2   NA    e
3     3    4    a
4     2    4    b
5     1    3    d
6     2    4 <NA>
7    NA    1    b
8     1   NA    e
9     3    3 <NA>
10    1    2    e
11    1    4    e
12   NA    1 <NA>
13    3   NA    a
14   NA    4    c
15    3    3    b
16    2    3    e
17    3    1    e
18   NA    2    b
19   NA    5    c
20    3    5    e
```