# Passing a column name to R tidyr spread

Tags: r, tidy, spread

I am trying to pass an object with the column name to the spread function, but instead of reading the value inside the object it just tries to use the object name itself

Here just a toy example

```
library(tidyr)
d = (1:4)
n = c("a"," a", "b","b") 
s = c(1, 2,5,7) 

df = data.frame(d,n, s) 

Value <- n
data_wide <- spread(df, Value , s)
```

> Error: Key column 'Value' does not exist in input.

whilst below works fine:

```
data_wide <- spread(df, n, s)
d  a  a  b
1 1 NA  1 NA
2 2  2 NA NA
3 3 NA NA  5
4 4 NA NA  7
```

Comment: Was that space in 2nd "a" intentional? `n = c("a"," a", "b","b")`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We can use `spread_()` to pass variable names as strings:

```
library(tidyr)
# dummy data
df1 <- data.frame(d = (1:4),
                  n = c("a", "a", "b", "b") ,
                  s = c(1, 2, 5, 7)) 

myKey <- "n"
myValue <- "s"
spread_(data = df1, key_col = myKey , value_col = myValue)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 dcast(setDT(df), eval(as.name(myValue))~ eval(as.name(myKey)), value.var=myValue)
```

Regarding passing names in `tidyr` functions, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37648980/r-fill-down-multiple-columns/37648994#37648994) could also help (which was posted a couple of hours back).

Answer (score 0):

looks like `tidyr` recognize it automatically now - it works both ways: type in the column names or put them in strings

```
stocks <- data.frame(
    time = as.Date('2009-01-01') + 0:9,
    X = rnorm(10, 0, 1),
    Y = rnorm(10, 0, 2),
    Z = rnorm(10, 0, 4)
)
stocksm <- stocks %>% gather(stock, price, -time) # make it to skinny table

# make it wide table
stocksm %>% spread(stock, price)

# time          X           Y          Z
# 1  2009-01-01  0.7444343 -0.07030219  0.9140019
# 2  2009-01-02  1.1988507  2.98659296  5.3044361
# 3  2009-01-03 -0.4344259 -0.11526884 -3.8380602
# 4  2009-01-04  0.8154400  2.08313458 -0.1152524
# 5  2009-01-05  1.1965647 -0.59055846  3.5647410
# ...



# it's same if put column names in strings
stocksm %>% spread('stock', 'price')

# time          X           Y          Z
# 1  2009-01-01  0.7444343 -0.07030219  0.9140019
# 2  2009-01-02  1.1988507  2.98659296  5.3044361
# 3  2009-01-03 -0.4344259 -0.11526884 -3.8380602
# 4  2009-01-04  0.8154400  2.08313458 -0.1152524
# 5  2009-01-05  1.1965647 -0.59055846  3.5647410



# or put in string variables
col1 = 'stock'
col2 = 'price'
stocksm %>% spread(col1, col2)

# time          X           Y          Z
# 1  2009-01-01  0.7444343 -0.07030219  0.9140019
# 2  2009-01-02  1.1988507  2.98659296  5.3044361
# 3  2009-01-03 -0.4344259 -0.11526884 -3.8380602
# 4  2009-01-04  0.8154400  2.08313458 -0.1152524
# 5  2009-01-05  1.1965647 -0.59055846  3.5647410
```